# How to disable 404 header on specific Wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I use this code to redirect specific url to a php file on my custom made Wordpress theme:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
if ( trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/') === 'pagename' ) {
include(locate_template('mysciprt.php'));
exit();
}});
```

(I know i can use rewrite rules but i need to use this code for a few reasons).

It's work's great. the problem is the page still has a http header with 404 status. and that's a problem for a few reasons (some of them are: seo, post scripts cant be used...).

**My question is:** Is there any way to fix it?

**What i have tried:**

I tried adding:

```
global $wp_query;
status_header(200);
$wp_query->is_page = true;
$wp_query->is_404  = false;
```

Didn't help at the beginning, then i changed my `action('wp'..` to `action('init'...` and it works! but the problem is the reason i am using the `'wp'` and not `'init'` is because i need to use `get_query_var()` on this script and i can't when using the `'init'` action.

Comment: I guess the pre_handle_404 hook would be an appropriate place to do this. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/handle_404/

Comment: This is not the right way to do this. Look at the template_include filter. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Comment: thanks. @CBroe. can you explain what exactly should i do to use it? btw - i updated some ideas i tried.

Comment: Check the comment at the beginning of the method I linked to; if your function for the filter `pre_handle_404` returns false, then it steps out of that hole 404 handling right there, so you should get the "default" status code 200.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

End up to be simpler then i thought:

Just added:

```
global $wp_query;
status_header( 200 );
$wp_query->is_page = true;
$wp_query->is_404=false;
```

To the script.php file itself before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a header with a 200 status code. Try this:

`header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`

Comment: something must have sent the 404 header before it hits your code then. check earlier in the script

Comment: BTW you don't need wordpresses get_query_var() function to get query vars. You can get them all through the $_GET array.

Comment: yes i was thinking of going that way, but 1. i have a lot of already made code using it (ok maybe that's not a good enough reason :) 2. i am afraid other things won't work in the future if i will need to use other functions that might be effected in the same way, just feels unstable to me...